# How can I display nested records on activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So far I have two models, user and profile

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

On my active admin model

```
form  do |f|
  f.inputs "User" do
    f.input :email
    #code to get the profile data
  end
  f.action :submit
end
```

So I want to get the profile data on the user form I have tryed couple of things but I wasn't able to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
f.inputs 'Profile', :for => [:profile, f.object.profile || Profile.new] do |profile_form|
  profile_form.input ...
  ...
end
```

inside the f.inputs "User" block should work.  Just set up the attributes of Profile inside this block using profile_form.